# Card in CarouselView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, carousel

I want to create an app in which I have to display carousel view as following picture. And I hav no experience with carousel view in past specially with card type views

[image: carousel View design which I need]

Comment: you can achieve this with viewpager2

Comment: You can use carousel library full feature for working with carousel
https://github.com/alirezat775/carousel-view
Document link here
https://github.com/alirezat775/carousel-view/wiki